# Webpack migration v4 to v5

Tags: webpack

How to write the following code in Webpack v5?

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
  }
};
```

I saw the changes in the migration notice, but I don't quite get it.

Answer (score 0):

In your `module.export` like you have in question. remove `node.fs.empty` and replace with below

```
...
    resolve:
            {
                fallback: {
                    fs: false
                }
            },
...
```

Comment: This answer needs clarification and more context please.